# Trying to hit mongodb from rest api and trying to perform post opertaion is giving EOFException

Tags: java, mongodb

I have hosted tomcat and MongoDB as a service in server. And I have also deployed war file in web app folder. Now when i'm trying to hit database from rest api and trying to perform a post operation using postman i'm getting an `EOFException`.

Please help me on this. I'm stuck with it for an entire day...
My basic code which establishes connection with MongoDB:

```
public class MongoDBSingleton {

private static MongoDBSingleton mDbSingleton;

private static MongoClient mongoClient;

private static DB db;

private static final String dbHost ="192.168.1.xxx";

private static final int dbPort = 27017;

private static final String dbName = "PetCareDB";

private MongoDBSingleton() {

};

public static MongoDBSingleton getInstance() {
    if (mDbSingleton == null) {
        mDbSingleton = new MongoDBSingleton();
    }

    return mDbSingleton;
}

public DB getDB() {
    if (mongoClient == null) {
        try {
            mongoClient = new MongoClient(dbHost, dbPort);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    if (db == null)

    {
        db = mongoClient.getDB(dbName);
    }
    return db;
}
```

I have tried running locally everything works fine but only when I host it on server it gives me following exception:

```
    Jul 11, 2016 4:56:17 PM com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector initDirectConnection
WARNING: Exception executing isMaster command on /192.168.1.50:8081java.io.EOFException
at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:48)
at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:33)
at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:28)
at com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:40)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:124)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:88)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:143)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:148)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.initDirectConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:548)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.checkMaster(DBTCPConnector.java:527)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:277)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:257)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:310)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:295)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:727)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:669)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.createIndex(DBApiLayer.java:364)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.createIndex(DBCollection.java:484)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.ensureIndex(DBCollection.java:560)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.ensureIndex(DBCollection.java:538)
at com.six30labs.petcareapi.services.Service.signUpUser(Service.java:51)
at com.six30labs.petcareapi.resources.MyResource.signUp(MyResource.java:93)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
```

Comment: Is your mongo instance on your server running? If it is, try restarting it. Verify that the credentials your use to connect with in your code work on that instance for that database (open a mongo shell on the server and test it)

Comment: @CaseyMurray : It is running on server..The code and credentials are also correct..I have also tested the same code in locally and also on test server it works like a charm.. It is only creating a problem when I export as war file & host it on main server and performs a post/get operation..Wondering if Tomcat/mongo has something got to do with fire wall settings..

Comment: Try with something simpler, connect from your production server instance to MongoDB using mongo shell and see whether it works. You may also be benefited by checking out [mongodb: production notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/)